# Make changes in parent tag from nested tag

Tags: javascript, riot.js

Have a recursively nested tag:

```
<list>
   <div if="{ items }">
      <div each="{ items }">
         <input type="checkbox" checked="{ selected }" onclick="{ parent.select }"> {name}
         <list />
      </div>
   </div>

   var parent = this.parent
   select(e) {
     var item = e.item
     item.selected = !item.selected
     parent.selected = item.selected // does not change parent's checkbox "checked" state
     return true
   }
</list>
```

It is mounted as follows:

```
riot.mount('list', { 
  items: [
     {name: "Item 1"},
     {name: "Item 2", selected: true, items: [
        {name: "Item 2.1", selected: true, items: [
           {name: "Item 2.1.1}
        ]}
     ]}
  ] 
})
```

As described in comment in a tag code - there is a problem in changing parent's checkbox "checked" state. But "selected" property's value changes as expected.

Is it possible somehow to change parent's checkbox state or call "select" method for parent tag?

Answer (score 1):

Only the element which has a eventhandler fired will be updated automatically. To change the view outside the element, you need to update it manually.

```
parent.selected = item.selected
parent.update()
```